# Create git new branch and update it before first push

Tags: git

Currently when I create a new branch in git bash using: `git checkout -b <newbranch>`, this doesn't have any tracking information on the new branch. I am aware that if I make some changes and push it, it will auto create a remote branch e.g. `origin/<newbranch>` and set my local new branch to track the remote new branch; this is possible via git config setting.

But the problem is I can't take update from master using `git pull` before I make 1st push to the local new branch because it won't have a upstream set up until the 1st push. What's the "right" way to create a new branch in git to allow taking update before the 1st push to it?

Answer (score 1):

If you have created a new branch locally, but haven't made any commits to it, then the HEAD of the new branch is essentially just a pointer to some other branch whence it was created.  So it doesn't make sense to speak of doing a `git pull` on this new branch just yet, because as you pointed out, there is no tracking branch yet.  Even if you have made some commits, and the HEAD points to your own work, there is no upstream from which to take information.  Rather, the only new source of information is the original branch from which you created your branch.  So I interpret your requirement as bringing in new information from the source branch.

Instead, after you have committed your new local work, you may rebase on the original source branch:

```
get fetch origin
git rebase source
```

This would bring in any new commits from your source branch, and then reapply your not-yet-pushed local commits.  The gist of my answer is that if you haven't pushed, then the only source of new information is the branch from which you created your new branch.

Comment: If I created a new branch when I am on a local non-master branch, what's the HEAD of the new local branch? You said it's just a pointer to some other branch when it was created, is it the same as the HEAD of local non-master branch where I created the new branch? I agree with `git fetch origin` but why rebase afterwards? Why not git merge? Or it's the same in this case?

Comment: @stt106 Yes, when you create a new branch without committing, your HEAD points to the same commit as the source branch.  This _isn't_ the case once you have made commits.  But, if you haven't pushed yet, then there can't possibly be any new information coming in by means of your new local branch.

Answer (score 1):

Having created a local branch `branch`, you can set up remote tracking of `origin/branch` by saying

```
git branch -u origin/branch branch
```

But if the first update is coming from the remote repo, why manually create the loacl branch in the first place?

```
git fetch
```

Now you have the remote tracking ref.

```
git checkout branch-name
```

Assuming there's only one remote for which you have a tracking ref named `<remote>/branch-name`, this will create the local branch and set up tracking.

Comment: The first update comes from the remote master which I don't want to track from a new local branch.

Comment: @stt106 : What that really means is, you crated the branch at the wrong commit - which is different from the question you asked.  Just move the branch.  (Or, if you already have local commits, you can rebase.,)

Comment: Sorry my git is rather basic (as you can probably tell already), do you mean I shouldn't have created the new local branch where I created it from? I am hoping I don't have to create a new local branch from the last master every time, or my assumption is wrong?

Comment: @stt106 - When you create a branch, the whole point is that you're going to make changes independent of anything that happens on `master` (or any other existing branch) until you explicitly combine the changes (by merging or rebasing).  If you get an update from master before you've made any changes, and decide you want to start your branch there instead of where you originally started it, move the branch (`git checkout master; git branch -f my-branch-name`).  If you've already made changes and want to integrate `master` changes, either merge or rebase.